# Highcharts sunburst - override global colors

Tags: javascript, highcharts, sunburst-diagram

Is it possible to override global chart colors for sunburst chart? I tried multiple approaches but none seems to work.

Please check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/max1tdzh/

```
chart: {
    height: '100%',
    colors: ['#ff0000', '#00ff00', '#0000ff']
},    
plotOptions: {
    series: {
         colors: ['#ff0000', '#00ff00', '#0000ff']
     },
     sunburst: {
         colors: ['#ff0000', '#00ff00', '#0000ff']
     }
},
```

I have tried setting chart.colors, plotOptions.sunburst.colors and plotOptions.series.colors and none seems to work.

What works is setting color property on specific data points in series.data array but this solution is not nice as it requires loop over all elements using custom helper function like this:

```
let colorIndex = 0;
return data.map((point) => {
    if (!point.parent) {
        const color = colors[colorIndex % colors.length];
        colorIndex++;
        return { ...point, color };
    }
    return point;
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the colors directly in the chart configuration object:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    colors: ['#ff0000', '#00ff00', '#0000ff'],
    chart: {
        height: '100%',
    },
    ...,
    plotOptions: {...}
});
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/be61rtz2/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/colors

Comment: Following the [API](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.sunburst.colors) we should be able to define the colors in `plotOptions.sunburst.colors` too. Maybe it's a bug ?

Comment: jeez thanks! I got that one wrong from the doc, but I agree with Core972 it should be also possible to set it through plotOptions... But anyways, thanks

Comment: Hi, Yes, this problem looks like a bug. I have created an issue here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/10522